# How to start with javascript engine exploitation

Tags: javascript, exploit-development

I am beginner in exploit development. My experience is developing buffer overflow exploits and shellcoding. Now I want to begin with javascript engine exploitation.

1.What are five papers, books, articles that should I read to begin.

2.What is the best vulnerability that is simple and quite recent,so it is good to practice on.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question and does not fit the Q&A style here. If you can narrow down your question to specific things, we'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: Your edit still does not fit the Q&A format here. Requests for lists can end up going on forever.

Comment: I would suggest starting on simple buffer overflows without DEP and ASLR when beginning exploit development. Javascript engines are usually JIT compilers, not a friendly subject to start off with. Oh yeah and also maybe don't try to rip off Christopher Domas' handle when you want to be taken seriously.